# Admob ad showing error in xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

I am stuck in a problem and search alot but could'nt find the solution  here is my code

```
    <com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

This code show

```
Error parsing XML:unbound prefix
```

when i remove app:adUnitId and app:adsize it do not give any error, how can i remove this error?

Comment: What is your namespace definition for `app`?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is typographical, you're setting:

```
app:adSize="BANNER"
app:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"
```

But it should be:

```
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Once you solve your issue, both for reputation and feedback purposes, you should accept the answer that helped you most. You can do this selecting the 'tick' below the votes of the answer that you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

`xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Add this to your parent tag.

In my case.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Hope this will work.